# Indian algorithm using while loop

Tags: c

I need a bit help with my coursework This is indian algorithm if you never heard of it. 
I can easily do this using recursion, but can't figure how to work it out using loop? Any hint or suggestion?

Indian Algorithm:

```
3^10 = square (3^5)           
3^5 = 3 * (3^4)               
3^4 = square (3^2)            
3^2 = square (3^1)            
3^1 = 3 * (3^0)               
3^0 = 1
```

---

```
double powerloop(double x, int n)
{
  double m=x;
  if (n==0) 
    return 1;
  while(n>1)
  {
    if(n%2==0)
    {
      m=m*m;
      n=n/2;
    }
    else
    {
      m=m*x;
      n=n-1;
    }
  }
  return m;
}
```

Comment: Also, we'd actually need to know what the Indian algorithm is if you're asking us to check whether this works.

Comment: Agreed.  The google search for indian algorithm comes up with *this post* as the top result, and I see no other meaningful entries.

Comment: Looks like copy&paste from http://forum.notebookreview.com/programming-homework-questions/426810-how-implement-indian-algorithm-using-while-loop.html - there are also answers available

Comment: It could be to compute x^y in log n time: http://baibingz.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/indian-power-algorithm/

Comment: Do they call `repeated squaring` as Indian algorithm? Never knew :D

Comment: your solution doesn't look too wrong. If I were you, I would just do my homework, instead of asking here. Asking here doesn't really help you, in the end

Comment: I just wanted to know what's wrong with my code. I don't want to just go on forums and copy and paste other people's work.

Comment: put `printf`s in your code, or learn to use a debugger, and you will find out

Comment: @IncrosnatuBogdan: If you have problems with your code, you should always describe them, e.g. show the output you expect, and the output you actually get, and describe what you've done to try to figure out why they're different.

Comment: The Wikipedia article for this algorithm is: [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). There is even an example implementation like the one haccks supplied below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
double powerloop(double x, int n)
{
    double m = 1;

    while (n != 0)
    {
        if (n % 2 == 1)
        {
            m *= x;
                --n;
        }

        x *= x;
        n /= 2;
    }

    return m;
}
```

For more detail, see [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question says this is for a course and asks for hints or suggestions.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but answers with just code and no explanation are generally not very useful.

Comment: well, not really a hint ;-)

Comment: Should x *= x be actually m *= m ?

Comment: @Archie; No. `x *= x` is correct. Return value is `m`. Dry run this program (for shake take 2^3) and you will understand.